# PHP Warning: parse_ini_file() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php

При запуске скрипта КРОНОМ вылетает ошибка. Не могу понять, где и как включить эту функцию для всех .

```
PHP Warning: parse_ini_file() has been disabled for security reasons
```

Comment: есть доступ по ssh?

Comment: да, у меня vds.

Comment: вы эту функцию используете в кроне?

Comment: да, использую. Она нужна .

Comment: откройте тогда `php.ini` файл и уберите `parse_ini_file` из `disable_functions`

Answer (score 1):

Причина в `php.ini`. Там есть блок запрещённых функций (`disable_functions`), и, по всей видимости, `parse_ini_file()` тоже там указана. Просто уберите её оттуда.

Пример:

```
disable_functions = fopen, fwrite
```

т.к. запуск через Cron, редактировать нужно тот php.ini, который принадлежит php-cli, например `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini`

Comment: уже проверял. там стоит просто `disable_functions   = ` + полагаю, что тогда бы она для всех была закрыта ,а так - она работает при обычном пользовании сайта, а вот через крон - нет .

Может крон нужно с какими-то правами запускать

Comment: @SarkisAllahverdian дополнил ответ

Comment: я через поиск нашел все файлы php.ini , т.к расположение видимо другое у меня. Так вот , ни в одном из найденных файлов не прописано `disable_functions ` . Где тогда еще искать причину, не пойму

Answer (score -1):

Это предупреждение, а не ошибка! Он говорит: - Предупреждаю parse_ini_file() был отключен по соображениям безопасности, **т.е. обратись к хостеру своему**.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336103/parse-ini-file-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons-alternative/44238738

Comment: у меня ВДС, вся конфигурация за мной

Comment: Если ты всем владеешь, то и попробуй закоментить - ;disable_functions = exec,system,shell_exec,passthru,popen,pclose,dl,apache_note,apache_setenv,define_syslog_variables,pcntl_exec,syslog,posix_kill,posix_mkfifo,posix_setpgid,posix_setsid,posix_setuid,posix_setgid,apache_child_terminate,posix_getpwuid